# No network interface for the lan9118 emulated on QEMU 1.4.0 overo machine

Tags: networking, ethernet, qemu, embedded

Im using QEMU 1.4.0 Ubuntu 13.04 distribution.
Im trying to make the virtrual machine part of the host network so Im ussing this command:

```
sudo qemu-system-arm -M overo -m 1024 -sd ./test.img -clock unix -device usb-mouse -device usb-kbd -serial pty -monitor pty -net nic,vlan=1,macaddr=00:aa:00:60:00:01,model=lan9118 -net tap,vlan=1,ifname=tap0,script=no
```

In QEMU's monitor I see this:

```
(qemu) info network                                                             
hub 1                                                                           
 \ tap.0: index=0,type=tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=/etc/qemu-ifdown    
 \ lan9118.0: index=0,type=nic,model=lan9118,macaddr=00:aa:00:60:00:01

(qemu) info qtree                                                               
bus: main-system-bus                                                            
  type System                                                                   
  dev: lan9118, id ""                                                           
    mac = 00:aa:00:60:00:01                                                     
    vlan = 1                                                                    
    netdev = hub1port0                                                          
    bootindex = -1                                                              
    mode_16bit = 0                                                              
    irq 1                                                                       
    mmio ffffffffffffffff/0000000000000100
```

I see that the device is been emulated and the vlan attached to the tap device. So far everything looks good.

Inside the virtual machine I get this:

```
[root@overo ~]# ifconfig -a                                                    
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback                                             
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0                                   
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1                              
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                    
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                             
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)                                

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F2:9D:C9:7F:69:F7                         
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                               
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                    
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                                          
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

No eth0 interface was given to the lan9118 device. Insted I get a usb0 for which device is no where in the `info qtree` listing at the QEMU's monitor.

I guessed that it could be the drivers for the lan9118 weren't installed. So I checked the `linux-3.2.8.config` file and this is what the ethernet part does look like:

```
#
# CAIF transport drivers
#
CONFIG_ETHERNET=y
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_BROADCOM=y
# CONFIG_B44 is not set
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_CHELSIO=y
# CONFIG_DM9000 is not set
# CONFIG_DNET is not set
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_FARADAY=y
# CONFIG_FTMAC100 is not set
# CONFIG_FTGMAC100 is not set
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_INTEL=y
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_I825XX=y
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_MARVELL=y
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_MICREL=y
CONFIG_KS8851=y
CONFIG_KS8851_MLL=y
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_MICROCHIP=y
# CONFIG_ENC28J60 is not set
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_NATSEMI=y
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_8390=y
# CONFIG_AX88796 is not set
# CONFIG_ETHOC is not set
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_SEEQ=y
# CONFIG_SEEQ8005 is not set
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_SMSC=y
CONFIG_SMC91X=y
#CONFIG_SMC911X is not set
CONFIG_SMSC911X=y
# CONFIG_SMSC911X_ARCH_HOOKS is not set
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_STMICRO=y
# CONFIG_STMMAC_ETH is not set
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_TI=y
# CONFIG_TI_DAVINCI_EMAC is not set
# CONFIG_TI_DAVINCI_MDIO is not set
# CONFIG_TI_DAVINCI_CPDMA is not set
CONFIG_PHYLIB=y
```

I see CONFIG_SMSC911X=y which in this case should be good.
I also tried CONFIG_SMC911X=y but nothing changed.

If anyone has ever managed to bring an overo VM under the host network I will also be glad to hear from you.

Also, I tried getting a x86-64 VM to the host network using the same methode and it worked fine. The x86-64 VM use a e1000 device.

Looking at hw/overo.c on QEMU's code I see this:

```
88     /* Strictly this should be a LAN9221 */ 
89     if (nd_table[0].vlan) { 
90         /* The ethernet chip hangs off the GPMC */ 
91         NICInfo *nd = &nd_table[0]; 
92         qemu_check_nic_model(nd, "lan9118"); 
93         s->eth = qdev_create(NULL, "lan9118"); 
94         qdev_set_nic_properties(s->eth, nd); 
95         qdev_init_nofail(s->eth); 
96         omap_gpmc_attach(s->cpu->gpmc, OVERO_NET_CS, s->eth, 0, 0); 
97         sysbus_connect_irq(sysbus_from_qdev(s->eth), 0, 
98                            qdev_get_gpio_in(s->cpu->gpio, 176));
```

the comment at line 88 says it should be strictly a LAN9221 device, 
but the qemu_check_nic_model(nd, "lan9118") is a LAN9118.

What device driver should be installed then?

Looking at hw/overo.c on QEMU's code I see this:

```
88     /* Strictly this should be a LAN9221 */ 
89     if (nd_table[0].vlan) { 
90         /* The ethernet chip hangs off the GPMC */ 
91         NICInfo *nd = &nd_table[0]; 
92         qemu_check_nic_model(nd, "lan9118"); 
93         s->eth = qdev_create(NULL, "lan9118"); 
94         qdev_set_nic_properties(s->eth, nd); 
95         qdev_init_nofail(s->eth); 
96         omap_gpmc_attach(s->cpu->gpmc, OVERO_NET_CS, s->eth, 0, 0); 
97         sysbus_connect_irq(sysbus_from_qdev(s->eth), 0, 
98                            qdev_get_gpio_in(s->cpu->gpio, 176));
```

the comment at line 88 says it should be strictly a LAN9221 device, 
but the qemu_check_nic_model(nd, "lan9118") is a LAN9118.

I searched on internet and SMSC911X should be de same driver for both device.
    CONFIG_SMSC911X=y
I wondering if `CONFIG_SMSC911X_ARCH_HOOKS` should also be set. But the info about this config is not well detailed.

On smsc.com I found this; SRC-118-UBOOT-ARM
LAN91xx/LAN92xx UBOOT driver for ARM processor

But  have no idead If my uboot has does driver or even how to add them.